# Error "Variable is used before being assigned" in an Angular unit test although it's like in an article

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm new at Angular unit tests and try to test an API access.

Here's my code:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing'
import { JwtHelperService, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt'

import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service'
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service'
import { WorkService } from '../../services/work.service'
import { ErrorToLogService } from '../../services/errorToLog.service'

import { FooterComponent } from './footer.component'

describe('FooterComponent', () => {
  let component: FooterComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooterComponent>
  let httpController: HttpTestingController

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        UserService,
        WorkService,
        ErrorToLogService,
        JwtHelperService,
        { provide: JWT_OPTIONS, useValue: JWT_OPTIONS },
      ],
      declarations: [ FooterComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents()
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    fixture.detectChanges()
    httpController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController)
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule()
  })

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy()
  })

  it('Check API returns the webmaster',  () =>  {
    let res: string
    component.getUserService().getWebmasterEmail().subscribe(
      data => res = data,
    )

    const req = httpController.expectOne({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `/api/getWebmasterEmail`,
    })

    req.flush("toto")
    expect(res).toEqual("toto")
  })
})
```

The test `Check API returns the webmaster` doesn't compile because `Variable 'res' is used before being assigned`.

I kind of understand but I can't see why it would work better in the paragraph "Angular Service Unit Testing Example with HttpClient" of [this article](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/unit-testing-angular-services) (test "should return data").

Anyone to shed light on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.flush()` just means that you are resolving the promise. you'll still need to move your `expect` to within the promise.

```
it('Check API returns the webmaster',  () =>  {
    let res: string
    component.getUserService().getWebmasterEmail().subscribe(
      data => {
      res = data,
      expect(res).toEqual("toto");
    }
    )

    const req = httpController.expectOne({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `/api/getWebmasterEmail`,
    })

    req.flush("toto")
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've done this, but now Jasmine returns 'Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: GET, URL: /api/getWebmasterEmail", found 2 requests', designating the line "const req = httpController.expectOne(...)". I don't understand why.

Comment: check to see if your `getWebmasterEmail` function is being called automatically within your component. Somewhere like `ngOnInit`

Comment: Yes it is. Why is it a problem? And what's the standard way to deal with this?

Comment: It's not a problem at all, you just have to know how your code behaves and unit test accordingly. You can update your code to test that there are two requests let requests = httpTestingController.match(url); expect(requests.length).toBe(2);`

Comment: OK I've done as you say, with the line "req[0].flush("toto")". There's no more error thanks. but Jasmine should return one, because 'toto' is clearly not what the server returns.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it's working. The second one is returned by creating the component, not necessarily what jasmine is doing.

Comment: OK but is there really an access to the server?

Comment: probably. you can double check in the console > network tab. If you don't a call to your server, you need to put that spy in your `beforeEach` function.

Comment: Well I can see in the network tab the stream relative to the building of Jasmine/Karma page but no sign of the getWebmasterEmail request. And my Node API doesn't record any access. "that spy"? What do you mean? I guess "spy" designates the spyOn function but why "that"? Sorry if I abuse. I spend time on tutorials, but I'm still a bit lost.

Comment: in that case, then you are fine. I'm not familiar with how `httptestingcontroller` works behind the sense.

Comment: Fine? Well, Jasmine should return an error, because "toto" is not the email address of the webmaster.

Comment: you added "toto" yourself using `req.flush("toto")`

Comment: So it's just a simulation of an access to the server? I would like to compare with what really comes from the server. But maybe I should open a new issue as the original one is solved.

Comment: yes. When unit testing, you should never call an actual api.

Comment: But when a user is on a panel of my website, every click he makes causes an API access which returns buttons (corresponding with elements of the database) on which he can click in turn. How is it possible to unit test the front in these conditions? Almost nothing happens without API access.

Comment: this discussion is getting way to long to be in this chat, but in short, you mock everything returned from the API. There are just way too many things can go wrong when calling an api.